# std::function template with multiple template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

When looking for documentation on std::function, I found several pages, that list two implementations of std::function for C++11:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

> ```
> template< class >
> class function; /* undefined */
> template< class R, class... Args >
> class function<R(Args...)>;
> ```

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/functional.htm,

> ```
> template <class T> function;     // undefined
> template <class Ret, class... Args> class function<Ret(Args...)>;
> ```

- https://cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/

> ```
> template<class >
> class function;
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> template< class R, class... Args >
> class function<R(Args...)>
> ```

I tried to use the multi-parameter version of the function<>-template, but my code does not compile, neither with visual c++ 2017, nor with XCode or g++. Here is my sample code:

```
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
        std::function<void, int> cb;
}
```

All compilers complain on std::function taking only a single template parameter.

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: `void, int` doesn't look compatible with `R(Args...)`. `R` - return type. `Args...` - pack of arguments. Specify it as `void(int)`

Comment: You basically want to specify the template type as `ReturnType(Arg1Type, Arg2Type...)`. E.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/s4xoveqsE

Comment: typo: `std::function<void(int)> cb;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that list two implementations of std::function for C++11:

No they don't. That isn't what they're showing at all.

```
template< class >
class function; /* undefined */
```

is the base template, which (as it says), is never defined.

For example, `std::function<int>` would never make sense, so there is simply no template defined that could match that pattern.

```
template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>;
```

is a [partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).

That is, `std::function<T>` is *only* defined at all when `T` has the form `R(Args...)`, meaning `T` is the type of a function returning `R` and taking the arguments `Args...`.

Hence your attempt should be `std::function<void(int)> cb;` ... exactly as shown in the extensive examples at the bottom of the cppreference page you linked.

Answer (score 4):

The template argument list of `std::function` has a single type, as seen in the base template:

```cpp
template <class>
class function;
```

What you see in the following:

```cpp
template <class ReturnType, class... Arguments>
class function<ReturnType(Arguments...)> 
{
  ...
};
```

is a **partial specialization**, where the **types mentioned are used for pattern matching**. Essentially the specialization says:

"The type of `std::function`, that single type mentioned in the base template, is a callable type with such a `ReturnType` and such `ArgumentType`s